# How to provide parameters and call a js function inside a html and display the result as text based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to pass the parameters from my html to js and display the return value as text.

NOTE:
This is an angular page

My HTML code looks like this

```
<div data-ng-if="status.countWip" class="wip-count">
   test((status.countWipMin, status.countWipMax, kanbanboard.itemsCount[status.name])
</div>
```

My js function

---

```
function test(minCount, maxCount, artifactCount) {
 if(minCount !== -1 && artifactCount < minCount) {
  document.write("["+artifactCount+"/"+minCount+"]");
   } else if (maxCount !== -1 && artifactCount > maxCount) {
   document.write("["+artifactCount+"/"+maxCount+"]");
   }
};
```

Comment: if this is angular why are you using `document.write`. You could do this in angular way using `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your angularjs function to the view by using {{}} and the function should be defined on your scope.

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-if="status.countWip" class="wip-count">
       {{test((status.countWipMin, status.countWipMax, kanbanboard.itemsCount[status.name])}}
</div>
```

Angularjs

```
 $scope.test=function(minCount, maxCount, artifactCount) {
     if(minCount !== -1 && artifactCount < minCount) {
       return ("["+artifactCount+"/"+minCount+"]");
       } else if (maxCount !== -1 && artifactCount > maxCount) {
       return ("["+artifactCount+"/"+maxCount+"]");
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing Angular with native Javascript which is not a good idea for this scenario. If this is not angular and just a plain javascript then you should wrap the `test()` function with the `<script>` tag and `document.write` will replace the content of `div`

```
<div>
   <script>test(status.countWipMin, status.countWipMax, kanbanboard.itemsCount[status.name])</script>
</div>
```

Anyway this is for your understanding. Below is how you do in Angular way.

**Angular**

In Angular way,

Your mark

```
<div data-ng-if="status.countWip" class="wip-count">
   {{test((status.countWipMin, status.countWipMax, kanbanboard.itemsCount[status.name])}
</div>
```

Move the `test` function to the `controller` and use `$scope`

```
$scope.test = function(minCount, maxCount, artifactCount){
  if(minCount !== -1 && artifactCount < minCount) {
    return "["+artifactCount+"/"+minCount+"]";
  } else if (maxCount !== -1 && artifactCount > maxCount) {
    return "["+artifactCount+"/"+maxCount+"]";
   }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help @RemyaNair . Please set this as correct answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-init` when you want to call a function from your view, in your controller you can use `void` function to bind `$scope.result` for display in the view

**Html**

```
<div data-ng-if="status.countWip" class="wip-count" ng-init="test((status.countWipMin, status.countWipMax, 
    kanbanboard.itemsCount[status.name])">
    {{result}}
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.test=function(minCount, maxCount, artifactCount) {
    $scope.result;
    if(minCount !== -1 && artifactCount < minCount) {
       $scope.result= ("["+artifactCount+"/"+minCount+"]");
       } else if (maxCount !== -1 && artifactCount > maxCount) {
       $scope.result= ("["+artifactCount+"/"+maxCount+"]");
    }
};
```